# How to define multiword Model named relatioship method in laravel?

Tags: laravel

**My  model name "DiagnosisReport" i want to make hasMany relationship with "Prescription"  model .So what should be the method name in Prescription class ?I define the bellow method in Prescription class .But it does not work**

```
       <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    
    class Prescription extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        use SoftDeletes;
        protected $guarded=[];
        public function patient()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Patient::class);
        }
    
        public function appointment()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Appointment::class);
        }
        public function doctor()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Doctor::class);
        }
    
        public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
        {
        
            return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
        }
        public function DiagnosisReport()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(DiagnosisReport::class);
        }
        
        

}
```

here is my Prescription class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class DiagnosisReport extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function prescription()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Prescription::class);
    }
}
```

when i want to retrieve data i got Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\clinic\resources\views\diagnosis_report\index.blade.php)

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('css')

@endsection
@section('content')

<br>
<div class="br-pagebody">
   <div class="br-section-wrapper">
       @include('include._message')
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <h6 class="br-section-label">diagnosisReports List</h6>
         </div>



         <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-3">
          @if(Auth()->user()->role_id==2)
             <a href="{{route('diagnosis.report.create',$prescriptionId)}}" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 35px">Add New diagnosisReport</a>
          @endif
            </div>
         
     </div>

   </br>
     
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-colored table-dark">
      <thead class="thead-colored thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Patient Name</th>
                <th>Patient Email</th>
                <th>Doctor Name</th>
                <th>Document Type</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>


        </thead>   
     <tbody>   
        @foreach($diagnosisReports as $diagnosisReport)
          <tr>
              <td class="center">{{$diagnosisReport->created_at}}</td> 
              <td class="center">{{$diagnosisReport->presecription->id}}</td>
              <td class="center">{{$diagnosisReport->presecription->patient->email}}</td>
              <td class="center">{{$diagnosisReport->presecription->doctor->name}}</td>
              <td class="center"></td>
                     
              <td class="center">
                   
                  @if(Auth()->User()->role_id==2)
                  
                  {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['diagnosisReports.destroy', $diagnosisReport->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
                  {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                  {!! Form::close() !!}
                  @endif
              </td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>  
    </div><!-- table-wrapper -->
        

  </div>
</div>

                      
        
@endsection
```

Comment: if your class is named `DiagnosisReport` you should reference it like that (the same case) ... but what "does not work"? you can name the method what ever you want

Comment: i have changed my code but still same problem..can you check my code again.i have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **DiagnosisReport** model define a relationship like:

```
public function prescription()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Prescription::class);
}
```

and the, in your DiagnosisReportController, when you wanted to get the list diagnosisReport and it's prescriptions, you do something like:

```
$report = DiagnosisReport::with('prescription')->get();
```

It will get all the diagnosisReports with all of their prescriptions.

Comment: they are asking how to name the relationship in the Prescription model

Comment: i have changed my code but still same problem..can you check my code again.i have edited my post

Comment: @RabbiMahmud, Now your approach is correct. but you have a spelling error for prescription in your view: $diagnosisReport->presecription->id;

Comment: Rectify the spelling error in your view and you should be good to go.

Comment: The pleasure is all mine.